# Can't move a file after i write to it in python

Tags: python

[image]

[image]

I try to move the file, after I write to it, but it don't work. Why?

Comment: You change the variable `file` to be equal to the actual file-like object not the string. If you want to access the string again, you need to use different variable names

Comment: So, I have this vbs file. From python, I want to write to it some text, so i used "with open()" method. In that "open()" I passed the path for the vbs file, and then "w", to write to it. I named it file, as you cand see, and then i passed: "file.write("some text")

After that I tried to move the file to a specific path using shutil.move method. But it don't work

Comment: Also, please never post pictures of code instead of "real" textual code

Comment: wdym by "real" textual code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `file` variable is being overwritten when you use the `with` statement: by the time you get to the `shutil.move`, it is not the original string anymore. To solve this, use 2 different variables (e.g `filename` for the original string)